# Class not being added to parent div which contains an id beginning with x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to add a class to a parent container when the child element has the class 'hidden', if not it should add a different class.

```js
function tagMissions() {
  if ($('span[id^="mission_participant_new"]').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $(this).closest('div[id^="mission_panel"]').addClass('lss_new_case_in_progress');
  } else {
    $(this).closest('div[id^="mission_panel"]').addClass('lss_new_case');
  }
}

tagMissions();
```

```html
<div id="mission_474453321" mission_id="474453321" mission_type_id="239" class="missionSideBarEntry" latitude="48.464928" longitude="11.929025" target_latitude="null" target_longitude="null">
  <!-- this is the parent div i am trying to assign the class to -->
  <div id="mission_panel_474453321" class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="mission_panel_heading_474453321" class="panel-heading">
        <a href="/missions/474453321" class="btn btn-default btn-xs lightbox-open" id="alarm_button_474453321"> Alarm</a>
        <span id="mission_participant_474453321" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        <!-- this is the span element with the id beginning with mission_participant_new_ -->
        <span id="mission_participant_new_474453321" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk hidden"></span>
        <a href="" id="mission_caption_474453321" class="map_position_mover" target_latitude="null" target_longitude="null" data-latitude="48.464928" data-longitude="11.929025">Verkehrsunfall mit Linienbus</a></div>
    <div
      class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"><img src="/Bus_rot.png?1484350177" id="mission_vehicle_state_474453321" class="mission_vehicle_state"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
          <div id="mission_bar_outer_474453321" class="progress progress-striped mission_progress">
            <div id="mission_bar_474453321" class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="mission_missing_474453321" class="alert alert-danger">Zusätzlich benötigte Fahrzeuge: 1 FwK</div>
          <ul id="mission_patients_474453321"></ul>
          <ul class="mission_prisoners" id="mission_prisoners_474453321"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

So when a `span` element with an id beginning with `mission_participant_new` has a class called `hidden`, it should add a class to the parent `div` whose id begins with `mission_panel` called `lss_new_case_in_progress`. If the class `hidden` is not given, it should add `lss_new_case`.

This `<div id="mission_XXXXX">` is given many times within the DOM.
Can you guys help me out? I cannot seem to find the mistake.

Comment: `tagMissions()` isn't called in the context of an element, so what do you expect `$(this).closest(...)` to look for? `this` is the global `window` object.

Comment: Oh well, i was thinking that it was looking for the `span[id^=]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling `tagMissions` in the context of a DOM element, so `this` defaults to the `window` object, and `$(window).closest(...)` doesn't find anything.

It looks like you meant to loop over all the `mission_participant_new_XXX` elements, so you need to use `.each()` for this. It sets `this` to the current element of the iteration.

```js
function tagMissions() {
  $('span[id^="mission_participant_new"]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('hidden')) {
        $(this).closest('div[id^="mission_panel"]').addClass('lss_new_case_in_progress');
      } else {
        $(this).closest('div[id^="mission_panel"]').addClass('lss_new_case');
      }
    }
  });
}

tagMissions();
```

```html
<div id="mission_474453321" mission_id="474453321" mission_type_id="239" class="missionSideBarEntry" latitude="48.464928" longitude="11.929025" target_latitude="null" target_longitude="null">
  <!-- this is the parent div i am trying to assign the class to -->
  <div id="mission_panel_474453321" class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="mission_panel_heading_474453321" class="panel-heading">
      <a href="/missions/474453321" class="btn btn-default btn-xs lightbox-open" id="alarm_button_474453321"> Alarm</a>
      <span id="mission_participant_474453321" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
      <!-- this is the span element with the id beginning with mission_participant_new_ -->
      <span id="mission_participant_new_474453321" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk hidden"></span>
      <a href="" id="mission_caption_474453321" class="map_position_mover" target_latitude="null" target_longitude="null" data-latitude="48.464928" data-longitude="11.929025">Verkehrsunfall mit Linienbus</a></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"><img src="/Bus_rot.png?1484350177" id="mission_vehicle_state_474453321" class="mission_vehicle_state"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
          <div id="mission_bar_outer_474453321" class="progress progress-striped mission_progress">
            <div id="mission_bar_474453321" class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="mission_missing_474453321" class="alert alert-danger">Zusätzlich benötigte Fahrzeuge: 1 FwK</div>
          <ul id="mission_patients_474453321"></ul>
          <ul class="mission_prisoners" id="mission_prisoners_474453321"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also do it without looping, just using two selectors:

```
$('span[id^="mission_participant_new"].hidden').closest('div[id^="mission_panel"]').addClass('lss_new_case_in_progress');
$('span[id^="mission_participant_new"]:not(.hidden)').closest('div[id^="mission_panel"]').addClass('lss_new_case');
```

I also recommend you avoid using ID prefixes like this in selectors. Give all the elements with the same prefix a class, so you can just use `$('.mission_participant_new')` to find them.

Comment: I cannot change the html, i am only accessing the html with js in order to make some changes. Thanks for your answer!